# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils when deploying web application

Tags: java, jboss

Running JBOSS EAP 6.4.0.GA (AS 7.5.0.Final-redhat-21) in Windows 7.
Commons lang **is** deployed in path 
.\jboss-eap-6.4\modules\system\layers\base\org\apache\commons\lang\main\commons-lang-2.6.0.redhat-4.jar and module.xml in the same folder says

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.apache.commons.lang">...
```

As per [Red Hat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.4/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html), in In my web application's META-INF/MANIFEST.MF I have entry:

```
Dependencies: org.apache.commons.lang
```

Using Netbeans 8.0.2 I debug the application, but it fails to start with error:

```
[org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/TestApp]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) 
JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener 
instance of class com.netu.test.web.ContextListener: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
            at com.xxx.lib.db.ConnectionPoolSetter.setJdbcURL
(ConnectionPoolSetter.java:81)
```

So I get error about Jboss not finding class StringUtils, but that class is [in commons lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html).  Note that I do not want to deploy commons lang in my Web App's WEB-INF/lib. I want to use the module as it is installed in JBoss.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in /WEB-INF
2. Add the following XML:

   ```
   <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
     <deployment>
       <dependencies>  
         <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" export="true" services="import" meta-inf="import"/>
       </dependencies>
     </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```

Comment: Note to all: In order for "this" to work, you will have to create a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in WEB-INF and add the following xml:  <jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
<deployment>
  <dependencies>  
    <module name="org.apache.commons.lang" export="true" services="import" meta-inf="import"/>
  </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

It would be nice if @mrboo updated the answer.  I will mark it as correct.